# Search Layouts not available for Custom Object

Tags: lightning, custom-object, page-layout, search-layout

I can see the Search layout in my object after enabling **Allow Search**, but I can't see any layout where I can add my fields.
Please see the attached screenshot. How can I add layout in the Search layout?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you also need to add a Custom Tab in order for a record to be searchable.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_search_global.htm&type=5